# A moonless night

Tags: moon-phases

How can I tell in each month, when here will be no moon shining or seen at night?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to answer this yourself? For example, did you try searching on the web?

Comment: Depending on how you define 'night', the nights just before and after a new moon are also moonless, because the moon is either too close to the sun to be seen, or sets before twilight ends, or rises after twilight begins.

Answer (score 3):

A new moon (when the moon is not seen at night) happens regularly, every 29.5 days (roughly). This is roughly one day less than a month. So you can forecast the next few new moons by "add a month, minus a day"

The next New moon will be on 16 April. We would then expect new moons on:
15 May, 14 June, 13 July, 12 August and so on.

A website like [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/moon/phases/uk/london) will do the accurate calculations for you (adjusting for your local time and so on.